# structure format from array to array of object

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to form the structure like expectedOutput by iterating input array,but unable to form structure

```js
let input = ["lim","kim"]
let expectedOutput = [{id:"lim"},{id:'kim'}]

let newArr = input.reduce((acc,cur,i)=> {
acc['id'] = cur;
return acc;
},[])
console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: Try `let output = input.map((name) => ({ id: name }));` To edit your code - `acc.push({ id: curr });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map an object with a [short hand property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

```js
const
    input = ["lim", "kim"],
    result = input.map(id => ({ id }));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you are using `reduce()`. You can use `Array.map()`:

```js
let input = ["lim","kim"]
let expectedOutput = [{id:"lim"},{id:'kim'}]

let newArr = input.map(item => {
  return {id: item};
});
console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `map()`

```js
let input = ["lim","kim"]
const res = input.map(x => ({id: x}));
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
acc['id'] = cur;
```

Into

```
acc['id'] = acc.push({ id: cur });
```